# Froala editor doesn't work for Angular 4 with typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I using angular 4 with type script and I installed ng2-froala-editor and when I want to npm start occurs error

```
[at-loader] ./node_modules/ng2-froala-editor/ng2-froala-editor.d.ts:1:1 
TS6053: File './node_modules/typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts' not found.
errors @ client?0fb1:119
sock.onmessage @ socket.js?e5d0:37
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js?3e89:51
(anonymous) @ main.js?45b8:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js?45b8:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js?927b:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js?c17e:35
wrapFn @ zone.js?fad3:1075
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?fad3:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:191
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js?fad3:498
invokeTask @ zone.js?fad3:1370
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js?fad3:1388
```

I imported this:

```
import {FroalaEditorModule} from 'ng2-froala-editor/ng2-froala-editor';
```

into module.ts and this into component

```
import {FroalaEditorComponent} from 'ng2-froala-editor/ng2-froala-editor';
```

Anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angular-froala-wysiwyg` (i am using it in my project)

install it via

```
npm install angular-froala-wysiwyg
```

and import in app.module.ts

```
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
```

and also import in `@ngModule` decorator

```
FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(), FroalaViewModule.forRoot()
```

hope I will solve your issue